# How to import package modules from in-package "main" module

Tags: python

My package structure is:

```
main.py
mapp/
   __init__.py
   core/
     __init__.py
     tobeimported.py
   test/
     __init__.py
     (test modules)
   utils/
     __init__.py
     blasttofasta.py
```

The file **blasttofasta.py** is executed as script.

**blasttofasta.py** looks like:

```
import mapp.core.tobeimported

def somefunc():
   pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
  pass
```

But Exception occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "utils/blasttofasta.py", line 5, in <module>
    import mapp.core.tobeimported
ImportError: No module named mapp.core.analyzers
```

<s>How to import *tobeimported* module? I run the blasttofasta.py from top directory (where main.py is)</s>

EDIT: Maybe better question is: How to get mapp package to the sys.path? Because script file only see its own directory but not the package directory.

Thank you

Comment: python -m mapp.utils.test  << this works. But I don't know why it works and classic python mapp/utils/test.py didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I want to including blasttofasta.py or run it as script simultaneously mos important is to have directory containing mapp package in sys.path.

**This worked for me:**

Before importing mapp (or other module from this package) I wrote into blasttofasta.py:

```
import os
os.sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))+ '/../../')
```

This append mapp package path and I can run it as script. On the other side is no problem with is included in another package.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the absolute structure to import.

To import blasttofasta.py in tobeimport.py

## ToBeimport contents

```
from myapp.utils import blasttofasta
```

Your structure is good.

Answer (score 0):

Two things need to happen:

- Your `map` directory needs a `__init__.py` file.

You can simply do this (*naively*):

```
$ touch /path/to/map/__init__.py
```

- `/path/to/map` needs to be in `sys.path`

Please read: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html for more details.

Comment: If I run the blasttofasta.py from the directory containing mapp package then it is in sys.path, isn't it?

Comment: No. By default Python only adds the **current working directory** to ``sys.path`` and any **installed packages**. Please read the link I posted.

Comment: I readed it. If I let python show cwd (via os.getcwd()) it show the directory that contains mapp package. Is it not right?

Comment: You will need to be one level up. ``os.getcwd()`` should return the path that contains ``main.py`` so that ``from map import core`` works. Again read the documentation!

Comment: OK .. os.getcwd() return directory that contains main.py and mapp package/directory as well. It is the same level.

Comment: It does't include current working directory but directory containing the module. So it doesn't depent on the place from were I run the script but where the script is.